# Удалить все файлы кроме белого списка

Tags: linux, администрирование

Существует некая директория `/var/recs` содержащая 76763 файлов и 29400 вложенных директорий чей уровень вложенности не превышает `-maxdepth 1`. Так же, существует список "нужных файлов" (тех, что должны существовать в этой директории) из mysql содержащий 54721 `basename` (не содержащих путь к файлу) имён. Предо мной встала задача периодически удалять все файлы кроме тех, что есть в списке "нужных файлов". Пока для себя вижу простой путь: искать все файлы с помощью `find`, брать bash-скриптом `basename` и банально перебором искать его в списке "нужных файлов": При нахождении - переходить к следующему, в противном случае - удалять. Опционально, удалять пустые директории.

**Собственно вопрос:** может есть более правильный и/или быстрый способ это делать? Ну, например, привести списки к единому виду, отсортировать, с помощью `comm` сравнить и удалить лишнее. Может вообще не на `bash` делать? В общем, буду рад любым идеям :)

Comment: Я бы вместо баша взял питон, вместо списка множество, а в остальном так и делал бы

Comment: Белый список это очень устаревшая идея. Можно придумать две директории `white` и `tmp`. Белый не трогаем, а временную чистим. Искать по списку это лишняя работа. Удачи .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем файл `whitelist.txt` с содержимым:

```
file190
file195
file198
```

Создаем папку `test_folder` с файлами, названия некоторых из которых имеются в `whitelist.txt` :

```
touch /path/to/test_folder/file{190..200}
```

И удаляем все, кроме содержащихся в `whitelist.txt`:

```
grep -vw "$(< whitelist.txt)" < <(find /path/to/test_folder -type f) | xargs rm
```

Ну или так:

```
xargs rm < <(grep -vw "$(< whitelist.txt)" < <(find /path/to/test_folder -type f))
```

Соответственно глубину поиска удаляемых файлов задаем параметром `-maxdepth` для `find`

Ну и зачистим пустые директории:

```
find /path/to/test_folder -type d -exec rmdir -p --ignore-fail-on-non-empty {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ rm -rf !(my_very_important_file)
```

Либо если файлов мало, то:

1. Делаем хард-линки на нужные файлы в соседнюю пустую директорию.
2. Удаляем все файлы
3. Перемещаем хард-линки из соседней директории.

Comment: Хмм, интересный вариант, но наверно надо было упомянуть в топике, что эта директория разносится в кучу мест с помощью `lsyncd` и это не пойдёт на пользу сети :)